# Magento 2 - Tax settings

Tags: magento2, tax

I'm getting really frustrated with the tax settings within Magento 2.2.2

I have added products with a price, in the tax settings I set the setting to "Prices in catalog are within tax" also I set, show catalog prices incl. tax. But it keeps adding the tax to the product anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Need this configuration for tex calculation**

- Set Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Calculation Settings -> Catalog Prices in "Including Tax"
- Set Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Price Display Settings -> Display Product Prices In Catalog in "Including and Excluding Tax"
- rm -rf var/cache
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex

for more information refer this link : http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-settings-general.html